# Regex Validate French mobile number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate french mobile numbers:
I have already removed all non numeric character and the eventual 00 at beginning, and rules are:

> start with 06 or 07 or 09
>   is 10 digit long:

thus :

```
/^0(6|7|9)\d{8}$/
```

but (seems) that if countrycode (33) is present, the leading zero has to be avoided, but at this point I cannot create the right regex, since with number:

> 33614444444

```
/^(33|0)?(6|7|9)\d{8}$/
```

it works, but works also with

> 614444444

while it should not

can suggest solution?

Comment: would the 00 be in brackets ?

Comment: no, 00 is removed in advance
Now I remove from question to avoid misunderstanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it using the regex

```
^(33|0)(6|7|9)\d{8}$
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2jel5Q/2)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use `/^(33|0)(6|7|9)\d{8}$/` ?

I do not think you need the quantifier `?`.

When you add `?` after `(33|0)`. It implies either none of them is present or one of `33` or `0` is present.  It would match all the following -

```
614444444 // none present
0614444444 // 0 present
33614444444 // 33 present
```

Comment: because 33 is optional
while 0 is required, unless 33 is present

Comment: If `33614444444` and `0614444444` are the same number, above regex should work fine. This is what is evident from the question. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Joe thats what `(33|0)` means, you have either `33` or `0` not both